# Undo the "sudo" within a script

Tags: scripts, sudo

Is there any way to undo the `sudo` within the script?
like..

```
sudo ./script.sh
```

commands 1,2,3,4,5 with `sudo` rights

commands 6,7,8,9 without `sudo` rights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the manual for sudo:

> -k [command]
>
> When used alone, the -k (kill) option to sudo invalidates the user's cached credentials. The next time sudo is run a password
>   will be required.

So put a `sudo -k` before every `sudo` command you want to re-ask for a password. Or behind every command where you want the next commands not to be `sudo`.

---

By the way: if you ask for a password inside the script you should use ...

```
./script.sh
```

and not with `sudo` in front of it.

Comment: I did it with a "sudo" infront of every command that needs it and put a sudo -k befor the commands that don't need the sudo

Comment: @Ausrastor excellent :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have to run your script with sudo, you can still run some commands as a normal user using:

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER <command>
```

If you run the following script with `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami
sudo -u $SUDO_USER whoami
```

It will output:

```
root
sylvain
```