# Drop/Undo sudo privileges on .py file which runs inside a program which runs from sudo previleges

Tags: command-line, permissions, python, sudo, scripts

I need to run a program from sudo privileges and I am running `.py` file inside the program. So when my program runs from `sudo` then it automatically calls/runs the `.py` file with `sudo`. I am running file like

```
./myFile.py arg1 arg2
```

My requirement is that my program need to be run from `sudo` but when I runs/calls `.py` file inside program then it should runs as normal privileges (without `sudo`).

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Start your Python script inside your programm with

```
su -c '<your_python_script>' - <your_user_name>
```

---

***Examples***

```
$ sudo su -
$ whoami
root
$ su -c 'whoami' - aboettger
aboettger
```

or as script with the name `foo`

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
su -c 'whoami' - aboettger

exit 0
```

*example output*

```
sudo ./foo
root
aboettger
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I run file as per suggested by you like su -c "./myFile.py arg1 arg2" another_user and it works. But when I wrote this line inside .sh file and run .sh file using sudo then it does not works and it says "(process:3572): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused" on terminal

Comment: @manojpatidar You're welcome. The 2nd problem, I have no idea. I don't know what do you want to do in your script. This should be a new question. ;)

Comment: @manojpatidar Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓), this means, yes, the answer is correct. http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: I write the only line in my .sh file and did the same to test that it is working with sudo or not. Because as I have mentioned in my question description that " My requirement is that my program need to be run from sudo but when I runs/calls .py file inside program then it should runs as normal privileges (without sudo)" . I think if does not work in this case then the same may be happen when I run my program with sudo and run .py inside the same.

Comment: See and test my example, the `su …` is correct.

Comment: Yes your example works but my requirement is need to run program from sudo and run .py file inside program without sudo.

Comment: `su -c 'whoami' - <user_name>` is without sudo, `whoami` runs as `<user_name>`

Comment: If anybody there who has any idea about the issue then please let me know.

Comment: @User1234: I just needed this, fell on this answer and it works for me! (upvoted!)